# Passport req.user is undefined

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, discord

I understand that this question has been asked on here before, but the answers on those questions haven't helped me at all.

After the successful authentication of my user through passport with the "@oauth-everything/passport-discord" strategy, req.user is still undefined.

Here is the code in my main file,

```js
// Modules
const compression = require("compression"),
    cookieParser = require("cookie-parser"),
    cors = require("cors"),
    express = require("express"),
    exphbs = require("express-handlebars"),
    session = require("express-session"),
    logger = require("morgan"),
    path = require("path"),
    createError = require("http-errors"),
    mongoose = require("mongoose"),
    debug = require("debug"),
    flash = require("connect-flash"),
    passport = require("passport");

// Local files
const setupPassport = require("./src/setupPassport");

// Passport
setupPassport(passport);

// Mongoose
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/website", {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
}).then(() => {
    debug("sb:mongoose")("Successfully connected to mongodb.");
}).catch(e => {
    debug("sb:mongoose")("Unable to connect to mongodb\n" + e);
});

// Routers
const indexRouter = require("./routes/index");
const loginRouter = require("./routes/login");

// App setup
const app = express();
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views/pages"));

// View engine
app.engine("hbs", exphbs({
    defaultLayout: "user",
    layoutsDir: "./views/layouts/",
    partialsDir: "./views/parials/",
    extname: "hbs"
}));
app.set("view engine", "hbs");

// Middleware
app.use(logger("dev"));
app.use(compression());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
    secret: "replace with env secret",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {secure: true}
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(cors());
app.use(flash());
```

this is my setup passport file

```js
const pprt = require("passport");
const { Strategy, Scope } = require("@oauth-everything/passport-discord");
const User = require("../models/user");

/**
 * @param {pprt} passport
 */
module.exports = (passport) => {
    passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
        return done(null, user.id);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
        User.findById(id, (err, res) => {
            if (err) return done(err);

            return done(null, res);
        });
    });

    passport.use(new Strategy(
        {
            clientID: "no",
            clientSecret: "no way",
            callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/login/auth/callback",
            scope: [Scope.EMAIL, Scope.IDENTIFY]
        },
        (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) => {
            User.findOne({user_id: profile.id}, (err, res) => {
                if (err) return cb(err);

                if (!res) {
                    let newUser = new User({
                        user_id: profile.id,
                        username: profile.username,
                        displayName: profile.displayName,
                        email: profile.emails[0].value,
                        verified: profile.emails[0].verified,
                        tokens: {
                            access: accessToken,
                            refresh: refreshToken
                        }
                    });

                    newUser.save().then(user => {
                        cb(null, user);
                    });
                } else {
                    res.updateOne({
                        user_id: profile.id,
                        username: profile.username,
                        displayName: profile.displayName,
                        email: profile.emails[0].value,
                        verified: profile.emails[0].verified,
                        tokens: {
                            access: accessToken,
                            refresh: refreshToken
                        }
                    }, (err, user) => {
                        if (err) return cb(err);

                        cb(null, user);
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    ));
};

as i said req.user still returns undefined even after successful authentication does anyone have any idea why?

I should also mention that the user object is saved to mongodb perfectly which is why this perplexes me so much.
```

Comment: Seems correct, one thing I notice is that you can remove the async keyword from deserialzeUser, since User.FindById is using a callback

Comment: Where is your routes?

Comment: My routes are directly after my middleware. I got it working but I had to remove cooki-parser